# How can I solve a SCRAM authentication issue in Mongodb with Docker and Prisma?

Tags: mongodb, docker, prisma

When I try to run any command from the prisma I get this error message:

> $ npx prisma migrate reset

> Error: MongoDB error
> SCRAM failure: Authentication failed.
> 0: migration_core::state::Reset
> at migration-engine/core/src/state.rs:341

When I run docker ps:

> CONTAINER ID  | IMAGE      |      COMMAND       |           CREATED   |          STATUS   |          PORTS                    |                       NAMES

> 388a7219da3d | mongo:latest | "docker-entrypoint.s…" | About an hour ago | Up About an hour | 0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp, :::27017->27017/tcp | auction-mongodb

my schema.prisma:

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["mongodb"]
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Test {
  id String  @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  text String 
}
```

.env:

```
DATABASE_URL=mongodb://auction-user:password@localhost:27017/auction-db?authSource=admin
```

Comment: One of the pre requisites of using Prisma MongoDB connector is: Access to a MongoDB 4.2+ server with a replica set deployment. Has your local MongoDB database server have replicas enabled?

Comment: I don't think so, I'll test it here and then I'll tell you the result

Comment: Is there an update on this question? Have you found a solution @FabianoRocha?

Answer (score 14):

Simply add `?authSource=admin` to the end of your DATABASE_URL in `.env` file.

Comment: I did the same thing and it didn't work.

Comment: Thank you it worked, can you explain what that actually does?

Comment: it works, thanks

Answer (score 3):

in my case this code solved.
user and pw suppose to have root role.

```
DATABASE_URL="mongodb://root:example@localhost:3333/liz?retryWrites=true&w=majority&authSource=admin"

DATABASE_URL="mongodb://username:password@ip:port/db?retryWrites=true&w=majority&authSource=admin"
```

do remove +rsv if you want to connect to your local mongodb